# How to avoid disabling internet and GPS?

Tags: gps, internet, system

My friend have installed an app to watch the location of the children, BUT this app is useless if the kid can disable 4G internet and GPS. How to avoid disabling internet and GPS? Or is there some app to help on this matter?

Comment: Has your friend considered using a kiosk app solution? Kiosk  solutions usually lock down the device leaving only those settings, quick settings and the apps the administrator (such as, a parent) wants the intended user to use.

Comment: You can try this [kiosk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gears42.surelock) app which specifically claims to prevent access to wifi etc. It's well rated with good reviews - that's the reason for suggesting it. I have not tried

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access or adb on that device you could use an device automation tool like [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) and make it re-enable the gps and 4g if it is turned off
Triggers would be gps disabled and mobile service status -> diabled
and Actions would be location mode -> high accuracy and mobile data -> on
If you also want to lock wifi then add trigger: wifi state changed -> disabled and action wifi configure -> turn on
In end enable password protection in the settings to prevent anyone to disable the macro